# What is the correct syntax for get/set properties in Dart and how can I memorize the property syntax?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, properties

I find myself trying a couple of things before looking at the documentation about how to write a get/set property in Dart. I go

```
get int val => _val;
int val get => _val
val set(v) => _val = v;
```

and it does not make sense what the syntax should be. Is there an easy to remember rule-of-thumb for property syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you were writing functions instead of properties. It makes sense to start those functions with the words "get" and "set".

```
void setVal(int v) => _val = v;
int getVal() => _val;
```

Now separate the "get" and "set" words, make it compile by removing `void` for set and `()` for get, and you have properties!

```
set val(int v) => _val = v;
int get val => _val;
```